# Make a 2d menger sponge

Tags: code-golf, fractal

A menger sponge is a fractal made out of cubes within cubes within cubes...

If you start with a cube, on each face there are 9 squares. The middle square becomes empty (or 0). The other 8 squares iterate this process. They each get split up into 9 squares and the middle square face is taken out.

The goal today is to generate a menger sponge *face*, not the cube.

Here are some example given an input for the number of iterations.

```
0:
1
(No holes or anything, solid face)

1:
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1

2:
111111111
101101101
111111111
111000111
101000101
111000111
111111111
101101101
111111111
```

To complete the challenge, based on an input, return a set of 1 (filled in blocks) and 0 (empty blocks) with spaces between or not.

This is code golf, lowest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Also known as a [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
1¹.{³³┼┼≥:10ŗ;┼┼⁴++
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MSVCOS4lN0IlQjMlQjMldTI1M0MldTI1M0MldTIyNjUlM0ExMCV1MDE1NyUzQiV1MjUzQyV1MjUzQyV1MjA3NCsr,inputs=Mw__)

```
1¹                   push [1]
  .{                 input times do
    ³³                 duplicate top of stack 4 times, resulting in 5 total copies in the stack
      ┼┼               join the last 3 copies horizontally together
        ≥              put the joined at the bottom of the stack
         :             duplicate top of stack again
          10ŗ          replace 1 with 0 only in the top item
             ;         swap the top 2 items
              ┼┼       join the top 3 items horizontally together
                ⁴      copy the item one below top of stack
                 ++    add together vertically
```

Comment: Wow, impressive. Mind explaining it a little bit for people not as familiar with these types of languages?

Comment: @JohnPaulPenaloza while I'm writing an explanation, you could turn on the debug mode, click run, and step trough the program to see it live in action

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm new to code-golf style challenges and have never come close to solving one, I didn't know about the debug thing. Seeing these awesome solutions is really cool!